# How are some exotoxins heat-stable, despite being proteins?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, proteins

While studying microbiology, I came across bacterial exotoxins and endotoxins. It's understandable that endotoxins are lipopolysaccharides and hence heat stable.

Exotoxins are proteins and hence heat labile. But there are few exotoxins which are heat stable.

For example, Bacillus cereus produces two types of toxins that are involved in food poisoning— emetic toxin (heat stable preformed toxin) and diarrheal toxin (heat labile).

I don't fully understand the reasoning but I have a thought that, the heat stable exotoxins are small proteins/peptides which after denaturation (by heat) can refold back properly.

If anyone would help, it would be great!

Comment: Why do you think that these proteins _should_ be heat stable?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, I think heat would destabilize the protein folding, but small proteins might fold back...just saying

Comment: @ANandiΨ The construction "*Why few...*" in your title implies "Why are there not many?" But the body of your question suggests that you want to know "How are some exotoxins heat stable"? I'll make an edit, but feel free to roll back if not correct.

Comment: @ANandiΨ A priori, unless heat-stability is being selected for, one would expect that most proteins would not be head stable.

Comment: @acvill the edit is helpful... thanks